# Transformation with UDF to the same dataframe with `withColumn` fails

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm converting a string column to a hash with an UDF:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType
from datetime import datetime
import hashlib

hash_udf = func.udf(lambda x: hashlib.sha256(str(x)).hexdigest().upper())

udf_dt = func.udf(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x), date_format), TimestampType())

df.show()
id      | timestamp
1121234 | 20151112030203
9121234 | 20151112050203
8171234 | 20161112055211

df = df.withColumn('hashed', hash_udf(df.id))
df.show()
```

but it generates

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-3106d06b6e49> in <module>()
----> 1 df.show()

/usr/hdp/2.3.4.1-10/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate)
    255         +---+-----+
    256         """
--> 257         print(self._jdf.showString(n, truncate))
    258 
    259     def __repr__(self):

/usr/hdp/2.3.4.1-10/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
    811         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    812         return_value = get_return_value(
--> 813             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
    814 
    815         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/hdp/2.3.4.1-10/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     43     def deco(*a, **kw):
     44         try:
---> 45             return f(*a, **kw)
     46         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     47             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/usr/hdp/2.3.4.1-10/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    306                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    307                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 308                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    309             else:
    310                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o44.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 9113 tasks (1024.0 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1952)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$reduce$1.apply(RDD.scala:1025)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.reduce(RDD.scala:1007)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$takeOrdered$1.apply(RDD.scala:1383)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.takeOrdered(RDD.scala:1370)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.TakeOrderedAndProject.collectData(basicOperators.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.TakeOrderedAndProject.doExecute(basicOperators.scala:223)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BatchPythonEvaluation.doExecute(python.scala:359)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Project.doExecute(basicOperators.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ConvertToSafe.doExecute(rowFormatConverters.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Limit.executeCollect(basicOperators.scala:165)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectPublic(SparkPlan.scala:174)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1538)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1538)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:2125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1(DataFrame.scala:1537)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$collect(DataFrame.scala:1544)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1414)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1413)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withCallback(DataFrame.scala:2138)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.head(DataFrame.scala:1413)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.take(DataFrame.scala:1495)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.showString(DataFrame.scala:171)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

so it seems that the results are too large to be serialized because of

```
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 9113 tasks (1024.0 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)
```

but even if this is increased the error persists. What configuration should be changed so this small dataset can be processed?

Comment: I was able to run all of your code without generating an error. Are you running on the three row dataset listed above or on a larger dataset?

Comment: I'm running on a larger dataset, but I was able to reproduce the error with a dataset with 10 lines and 12 columns.

Comment: I recommend posting more extensive data, then, say those ten lines and 12 columns. Until I can reproduce your error, I can't debug it.

Comment: I would love to, but even this smail set is giving me errors. I believe that the error is not caused by the size of the dataset but because of the transformation, although the error indicates that the possible culprit is the serialization. If it helps, I'm running Spark 1.6.0 under YARN cluster mode with 32 executors, 8GB for each and 8 cores for each.

Comment: The set you have posted has two columns and three rows. When you run the transformation on those two columns and three rows, do you get the error?